# Why won't my text align with my image?

Tags: html, css, header, navbar

I want my logo, my description text and my nav bar to all sit along the same line at the top of my site. They won't align and I can't for the life of my figure out why. They are all on the same line, but the description text is sitting lower than the rest. Padding and margins don't seem to be making a difference.

```css
/* Title Area */

#title {
  float: left;
}
.sep {
  padding: 20px;
}
.desc {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
/*Topnav */

.nav-primary {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: floralwhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="title">
    <p>
      <img src="http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah150/beccaday02/blog%20title_zpsi4lf0fqz.png" />
      <span class="sep">|</span>
      <span class="desc">Help For The Undomesticated Homemaker</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-primary">
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/start-here.html">Start Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/write-for-us.html">Write For Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/advertise.html">Advertise</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    #title {
      float: left;
    }
    
    #title p {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #title p > * {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .nav-primary {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .nav-primary ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .nav-primary ul li {
      float: left;
      padding-right: 15px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="title">
    <p>
      <img src="http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah150/beccaday02/blog%20title_zpsi4lf0fqz.png" />
      <span class="sep">|</span>
      <span class="desc">Help For The Undomesticated Homemaker</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav-primary">
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/start-here.html">Start Here</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/write-for-us.html">Write For Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/advertise.html">Advertise</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have modified your CSS with the basic settings to align everything in 1 line, give the rest of the touch up as you wish

```
.header:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#title {
  float: left;
}

#title p {
  margin: 0;
}

#title p > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-primary {
  float: right;
}

.nav-primary ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-primary ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It hasn't made a difference. The image logo and the nav bar are exactly where they're meant to be, it's just the span class "sep" and span class "desc" that are too low down. They are sat right on the bottom of the div container and even if I add a margin to the bottom they don't move up.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

link:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well, I removed the Paragraph and simply used flexbox for a smooth and responsive header:

```
<div class="header">
<div id="title">
    <img src="http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah150/beccaday02/blog%20title_zpsi4lf0fqz.png"/>
    <span class="sep">|</span>
    <span class="desc">Help For The Undomesticated Homemaker</span>
</div>    
<nav class="nav-primary">
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/start-here.html">Start Here</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/write-for-us.html">Write For Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/advertise.html">Advertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.nappiesandnailpolish.com/p/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

and css:

```
/* Title Area */

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sep {
padding: 20px;
}

.desc {
padding: 20px 0px;
}

/*Topnav */

.nav-primary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
float:right;
margin-top: 1px;
}

ul.topnav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
}

ul.topnav li{
float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a{
display: block;
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: floralwhite;}
```

You can read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)